# FInding the Z coordinate using disparity map

Tags: computer-vision, disparity-mapping

I have found Disparity map of two stereoscopic images. And now I have to write an OpenGL code to visualize it for 3D reconstruction.

OpenGL has function vertex3f() for which three co-ordinates are to mentioned.

Two dimension are points on image.

So how to find `z` dimension using Disparity map?

Please suggest something on this.

Comment: Are your cameras calibrated?

Comment: No, I am doing 3D reconstruction using uncalibrated images.So,I can't use opencv function reprojectto3D as Q value is unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you have found disparity mapping, I assume that you are working with rectified images. In that case, the Z coordinate is given by simple similar triangle formulation,

z=Bf/d, where f if the focal length of the camera used (in pixels), d is the obtained disparity value for the pixel of interest and B is the baseline between the two stereo images. 
Note, the unit of z would be the same as that of B.